# Java regex that only accepts numbers and asterisks

Tags: java, regex

help with a regix that accepts the following:

```
*******-1234
```

I have the following but it doesn't work

```
 ^[0-9-*]
```

Comment: The string does not container "*only numbers and asterisks*". --- To use the character literal `-` in a character group, we need to escape it (`-` -> `\-`).

Comment: Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/2ErhkE/1 - it will accept numbers, dashes, and asterisks in any quantity.

Comment: @Turing85 you can also place it as the first element in that group, then it needs no escaping

Comment: @Turing85 ... or put it last

Comment: The exercise looks like these need to be in order. So any number of asterisks, then a dash, then numbers. You need at least 2 character classes for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the pattern matching the Asterix, hyphen and digits in order. Then use a quantifier for the repetition.

```
^\*+-[0-9]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ErhkE/2)